# Initiating camera capture from kernel module

Tags: camera, kernel, interrupts

I'm using global shutter cameras, is there a way to initiate a camera capture from within a kernel module? In particular from within an interrupt handler triggered by a GPIO?

Comment: Pls explain "global shutter camera". Also, what is the relevance of being "within a kernel module"?

Comment: System calls are different in KM and global shutter is relevant since we can define a frame/start time, IE we can start capture at a well defined point and stop it